# How do I specify the RowNode.id in ag-grid

Tags: ag-grid, ag-grid-ng2

I'm posting this here because this wasted a fair bit of my time today.

I was trying to set the `RowNode.id` from the data in the objects I set aggrid's `rowData` property to.  meaning, I wanted to use a property on my data model to supply the built in `id` field of ag-grid's row model.  They mention this in the documentation but they don't explain how to do itp.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The answer to this question is that you need to set the `getRowNodeId` property on the grid options object for the grid, like so:

```
// where 'd' is an object in your model
this.gridOptions.getRowNodeId = d => {
   return d.id; // return the property you want set as the id.
}
```

Answer (score 7):

To get ag-grid to use application assigned IDs, implement the grid callback getRowNodeId(). The callback should return back the ID for a particular piece of row data. For example, the following code snippet returns back the value of attribute 'id' for the supplied data item:

```
function getRowNodeId(data) {
    return data.id;
}
```

When providing IDs the following rules must be obeyed:

1. IDs must be unique
2. IDs must not change

If the attribute you are intending to use as an ID is either not unique or changes, it will cause unspecified behaviour in the grid. In other words, don't use a field that is not unique or can change.

If using Row Grouping, the grid will always assign IDs for the group level (as there is not a one-to-one mapping with application-supplied row data). The callback getRowNodeId() is only used for non-group level rows.

[Here's a link to documentation](https://www.ag-grid.com/javascript-grid-row-node/#application-assigned-ids)

Comment: with example, here -> https://www.ag-grid.com/javascript-data-grid/data-update-single-row-cell/

Comment: API changed to `getRowId({data})` in version 27.1.0, see https://www.ag-grid.com/javascript-data-grid/row-ids/, https://www.ag-grid.com/changelog/?fixVersion=27.1.0

Answer (score 3):

They actually not just mention about it, but also have a good example:

```
// callback tells the grid to use the 'id' attribute for id's
// id's should always be strings
gridOptions.getRowNodeId = function(data) {
    return data.id;
};

// get the row node with ID 55
var rowNode = api.getRowNode('55');

// do something with the row, eg select it
rowNode.setSelected(true);
```

Here is the [link to documentation](https://www.ag-grid.com/javascript-grid-accessing-data/#access-node-by-id).

Answer (score 0):

```
<ag-grid-angular
    class="ag-theme-balham"
    (gridReady)="onGridReady($event)"
    [columnDefs]="colDefs"
    [getNodeRowId]="getNodeRowId"
    [defaultColDef]="defaultColDef"
    (cellClicked)="onRowSelectionChanged($event)"
    (filterChanged)="onFilterChanged($event)"
    (gridSizeChanged)="onGridSizeChanged($event)"
  >
  </ag-grid-angular>
```

Find and Replace all GetRowNodeId to GetRowId, Name has been changed in Ag-grid ^30 version.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).